# Sharepoint file system permissions

Tags: sharepoint

In my sharepoint application I want to write log files to a certain folder on the hard drive. For users which are not administrators, the logs are not written. How can I  manage the permissions for such users in order to write the logs?

Answer (score 2):

You should call the log API in a RunWithElevatedPrivileges block. This will impersonate back the application pool account, to which you should give the right to write to the log directory.